# Unmet dependencies installing QGIS 2.0 on Ubuntu

Tags: qgis, installation, qgis-2

I have followed the instructions-[a link](http://www.digital-geography.com/install-qgis-2-0-on-ubuntu/) to install QGIS 2.0. Everything worked fine until the punch line, installing QGIS ( I do have Ubuntu 13.10);

```
sudo apt-get install qgis python-qgis qgis-plugin-grass 
eyalak@eyalak-ThinkPad-X220:~$ sudo apt-get install qgis python-qgis  qgis-plugin-grass
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:


The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python-qgis : Depends: python-qgis-common (= 2.0.1-2+precise1) but it is   
 not going to be installed
           Depends: libqgis2.0.1 but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: sip-api-8.1 but it is not installable
 qgis : Depends: libgdal1-1.7.0 but it is not installable
        Depends: libqgis2.0.1 but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: qgis-providers (= 2.0.1-2+precise1) but it is not going
        to be installed
        Recommends: qgis-plugin-globe but it is not going to be installed 
 qgis-plugin-grass : Depends: libgdal1-1.7.0 but it is not  installable
     Depends: libqgis2.0.1 but it is not going to be installed
     Depends: grass641 but it is not installable
 E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Not sure what to do on this one

Comment: Just for reference: http://askubuntu.com/questions/351899/qgis-quantum-gis-install-fails-unmet-dependencies

Comment: i have the same problem as you, i tried harder to install it root@khalid-Pc:/etc/apt# sudo apt-get install qgis python-qgis Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation: The following packages have unmet dependencies: python-qgis : Depends: python-qscintilla2 but i

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same problem and I did some trials before solving it. Finally this worked for me:

1. remove qgis and all the related packages
2. change the repository from ubuntugis to

> deb http://qgis.org/debian saucy main
>
> remove GRASS and existing version of libgdal
>
> install qgis again
>
> Hope this can help.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are trying to use the repositories for Ubuntu Precise 12.04 but you say that you are running Ubuntu 13.10. Make sure that you have only the correct repositories on your list.

The official instructions can be found on http://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html#ubuntu

Comment: I'm having the same issue: when trying to install the QGIS GRASS plugin, I get: The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 qgis-plugin-grass : Depends: grass641


I have installed both QGIS 2.0 and GRASS and they are both working fine...

Answer (score 0):

use the second method in this link

https://askubuntu.com/questions/351899/qgis-quantum-gis-install-fails-unmet-dependencies

1.Remove `http://qgis.org/debian` related line from `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

2.Uninstall any qgis and grass related packages using `apt-get autoremove` and then use the following command to install qgis.

```
   sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install qgis python-qgis qgis-plugin-grass
```